# How do I correctly stream a video file to the web with php or perl

Tags: php, perl, streaming, video-streaming, embedded-video

So I am new to Perl and web development but I was hoping to get some guidance on the following issue.

Server 1 is transcoding video for me and has an api endpoint for me to access. It will give me the file stream that I want to push to the web. 
So for the sake of the problem lets say that it is accessed at:

```
server1:123\video_stream
```

Server2 is my web server and I want to have a page that lets us access this video stream file

```
server2:80\web_stream
```

I have seen in php you can do `readfile("server1:123\video_stream)` but the entire video_stream will be read into memory before being output to the page... or so I was told.

I have also seen in Perl that ffmpeg output can but routed through the `open(DATA, $ffmpegProcess)` then printing the buffer read from this stream to the web_stream page...

This all assumes that the header information about the attributes of the video are correct.

Would it be as simple as making a curl request to Server 1 and returning that stream output like I can already with the ffmpeg output?

I am not looking for complete solution, just some direction on the best and most correct way to do this. Maybe php and Perl are not the right tools to handle this at all?

Comment: Is server1 visible to the Internet?  Then you can use [`<video>`](http://www.html-5.com/tags/video-tag/index.html#examples) or a Flash video player in your HTML so the browser will directly fetch the video and manage the streaming.  This avoids the CPU, bandwidth and complexity of passing it through server2.

Answer (score 0):

[ffserver](http://ffmpeg.org/ffserver.html) seems like the better tool to use. It's part of the ffmpeg family.

Answer (score 0):

PHP readfile() is a good way to do this. If you read the [PHP manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) the discussion tells you how to deal with different possibilites of reading the file in chunks and dealing with memory issues.